# How to link docker containers on Container VM with an manifest?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

**TLDR: Is it possible to link two containers with the container manifest?**

I'm trying to port the [Guestbook Sample app from the Google Container Engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/guestbook) to a [container vm](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms). I'm having troubles to connect the two container vms so the web app can access the redis service.

It works, if I'm using the docker command line on the instance:

start the instance and ssh into it:

```
gcloud compute instances create guestbook-vm --image container-vm --machine-type g1-small 
gcloud ssh guestbook-vm
```

create the containers:

```
sudo docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 dockerfile/redis
sudo docker run -d --name guestbook -p 3000:80 --link redis:redis -e "REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST=redis" -e "REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_PORT=6379" brendanburns/php-redis
```

I'm using the --link to connect the guestbook to the redis container. **Can this also be accomplished with the container manifest?**

this is my start command:

```
gcloud compute instances create guestbook-vm --image container-vm --machine-type g1-small --metadata-from-file google-container-manifest=containers.yaml
```

**EDIT: Solution from Alex to use 127.0.0.1 works fine, so that's the right containers.yaml:**

```
version: v1beta2
containers:
  - name: redis
    image: dockerfile/redis
    ports:
      - name: redis-server
        containerPort: 6379
        hostPort: 6379
  - name: guestbook
    image: brendanburns/php-redis
    ports:
      - name: http-server
        containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 3000
    env:
      - name: REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST
        value: 127.0.0.1
      - name: REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_PORT
        value: 6379
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no link parameter available in the container manifest](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms#container_manifest), so unfortunately you can't do it that way.

However, have you tried just setting the REDIS_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST environment variable to 127.0.0.1? I believe that should allow the frontend container to talk to the redis container through the standard networking stack.