# How to specify the container name running on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am running one container on GCE via

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container [INSTANCE_NAME]
--container-image='gcr.io/xxxxx'
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create-with-container

My question is how to specify the **container name**, which is similar to `docker run --name`.

Comment: What do you intend to do with that name? For this kind of naming, you would probably use the Compute Engine instance metadata (tags and labels), which allow you to identify the Compute Engine instance that was created. See the --labels and --tags options for that operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link docker containers on Container VM with an manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562704/how-to-link-docker-containers-on-container-vm-with-an-manifest)

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I need the `container name` to ssh. e.g. `gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE_NAME] --container [CONTAINER_NAME]`

Comment: @atline Do you mean it's impossible at this moment?

Comment: @northtree, No, I guess it can. In that answer, it use `--metadata-from-file google-container-manifest=containers.yaml`, and specify name in `containers.yaml`, but I don't know the current format of this as google will update it, but this works years ago, I guess. You just need to find how it looks like nowadays. As I'm not sure, so did not post a answer, just a comment for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to not be possible.

It's a reasonable request.

I recommend you file a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker for Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) and that you document use-case(s) for needing to query the container by the name there.

Use-cases help justify implementation.

[Issue Tracker for Cloud SDK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify the container name when creating the instance.

If your objective is to get to the bash shell of the running container, you can do the following:

1. ssh to the VM as usual with `gcloud compute ssh <instance-name>` after it is created with a deployed container.
2. Find the running container using `docker ps`, take note of the name of the container
3. Finally, do `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` and you'll bring up the bash shell for the running container.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I did before. Since the VM may have many containers, I just want to save time to pickup the `container-name` after `docker ps`.

Comment: I wanted to name my container so that I can create a shutdown script that will shutdown the container by name.